# BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()

Tags: laravel

When I use `auth()->user()->roles()` with tinker it works without any problem but when I use it on the web page itself I get:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()
```

What does this mean, what could be the reason for this? Here is the related model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function roles(){
        return Role::where('id', 6);
    }
}
```

I am using laravel 5.2 and the complete error is like below.

PS: *I guess the problem has something to do with the way I am using it in other parts of the site. Thats why it works on tinker. the other parts look like they require the result of the form of **Relation obj** which I can't provide after the where query.*

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.
in Macroable.php line 74
at Collection->__call('addEagerConstraints', array(array(object(User), object(User)))) in Builder.php line 667
at Collection->addEagerConstraints(array(object(User), object(User))) in Builder.php line 667
at Builder->loadRelation(array(object(User), object(User)), 'roles', object(Closure)) in Builder.php line 645
at Builder->eagerLoadRelations(array(object(User), object(User))) in Builder.php line 322
at Builder->get()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'get'), array()) in Relation.php line 343
at Relation->__call('get', array()) in Relation.php line 113
at BelongsTo->get() in Relation.php line 113
at Relation->getEager() in Builder.php line 676
at Builder->loadRelation(array(object(Comment), object(Comment), object(Comment)), 'user', object(Closure)) in Builder.php line 645
at Builder->eagerLoadRelations(array(object(Comment), object(Comment), object(Comment))) in Builder.php line 322
at Builder->get() in ModuleController.php line 27
at ModuleController->main(array())
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ModuleController), 'main'), array(array())) in Container.php line 507
at Container->call(array(object(ModuleController), 'main'), array(array())) in Container.php line 602
at Container->callClass('\App\Modules\Preview_coupons_comments\Controllers\ModuleController@main', array(array()), null) in Container.php line 502
at Container->call('\App\Modules\Preview_coupons_comments\Controllers\ModuleController@main', array(array())) in Facade.php line 219
at Facade::__callStatic('call', array('\App\Modules\Preview_coupons_comments\Controllers\ModuleController@main', array(array()))) in PageController.php line 220
at App::call('\App\Modules\Preview_coupons_comments\Controllers\ModuleController@main', array(array())) in PageController.php line 220
at PageController->getPageByName()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(PageController), 'getPageByName'), array()) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('getPageByName', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(PageController), object(Route), 'getPageByName') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(PageController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getPageByName') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\PageController', 'getPageByName') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckActive.php line 23
at CheckActive->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckActive), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 51
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Debugbar), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/Users/skeletor/Sites/project/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

this is the dd of the normal relation `$this->belongsToMany(Role::class);`

```
BelongsToMany {#971 ▼
  #table: "role_user"
  #foreignKey: "user_id"
  #otherKey: "role_id"
  #relationName: "roles"
  #pivotColumns: []
  #pivotWheres: []
  #pivotWhereIns: []
  #pivotCreatedAt: null
  #pivotUpdatedAt: null
  #query: Builder {#996 ▶}
  #parent: User {#319 ▶}
  #related: Role {#812 ▶}
}
```

and this is the modified `return Role::where('id', 6);` one

```
Builder {#812 ▼
  #query: Builder {#317 ▶}
  #model: Role {#997 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #macros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:11 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

*they look quite different and this may the reason.*

As @SimonSvensson asked here is my `Comment` model

```
class Comment extends Model
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['active', 'user_id', 'text', 'url'];

    /**
     * Comment morphs to models in commentable_type.
     * Get all of the owning commentable models.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        // morphTo($name = commentable, $type = commentable_type, $id = commentable_id)
        // requires commentable_type and commentable_id fields on $this->table
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * Query scope ofWebsite.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeOfWebsite($query)
    {
        return $query->where(function($q){
            $q->whereNull('commentable_id')->whereNull('commentable_type');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Comment belongs to User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        // belongsTo(RelatedModel, foreignKey = user_id, keyOnRelatedModel = id)
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact Laravel version you are using and the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: sure @SimonSvensson, I will add(edit) it.

Comment: Can you show us the Comment model?

Comment: @SimonSvensson yup I will add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to eager-load the User.roles relation, but it isn't a proper relation, it's just a method that invokes a call to Role::where(...). Relation methods are usually returning something like `$this->hasMany(Role::class)`.

Comment: Yes youre right I will reconsider it from this perspective.